# Unable to receive location in background continously with a foreground service in Android

Tags: android, background, location, google-play-services, android-gps

I can get valid location updates for a few minutes(On average 10 mins.) since a foreground service of type `location` is started. After this period, location received is null value or api callback is not invoked at all.

I am using `FusedLocationProviderClient` with `requestLocationUpdates(..)` api with priority `Priority.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` to get continuous location updates. I have provided permissions `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` already.

This is does not happen in all devices, but some devices, especially Vivo, Oppo etc. show this behaviour. The period in which location updates received got extended(On average, 20 mins) with disabling power saving mode, whitelisting my app to ignore battery optimisation etc. Still location updates are not received for a prolonged period.

Just to experiment, I tried adding an additional timer within foreground service in parallel to get single location update(FusedLocationProviderClient#getCurrentLocation) periodically with each of the following priorities too:

- `Priority.PRIORITY_PASSIVE`
- `Priority.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER`
- `Priority.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`
- `Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`

But still location update is null with this api after some period of time.

It gets curious how other apps like Uber resolved this problem. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Just FYI, background location permissions are not needed if you're running a foreground service that gets location. Background location permissions are only needed if your app gets location silently in the background, even if the app isn't running. For example, on my phone Uber and Strava only have the "allowed only while in use" location permission, but still are able to access my location while the app is running 'in the background', ie with a foreground service.